# Is there an ai to create more samples of an instrument from a single sample?

Tags: time-series

I don't know if there is a term for this.
Is there an ai to create more samples from a single sample?
a sample in music is a sound that has a unique pitch.
for example .sf2 files used in music applications like fl studio have multiple samples.
Sometimes I want an instrument that I hear in a song, so I want to extract all the samples from that instrument.
but sometimes there is only one sample of the isolated instrument because the other samples of the same instrument are contaminated with noise and superimposed on other sounds.
For example if I had the sound of a piano (source pitch), I would like to recreate all the pitches below and above that source pitch.

the basic thing is to stretch the source tone to have lower tones and shrink the source tone to have higher tones
but it seems that it does not sound the same as the instrument in the song.

Does anyone know if there is an ai that can recreate low and high tones and sound true to the instrument.

Comment: There are two approaches (which are related) a) oversampling eg SMOTE and b) creating variations eg VAE

Comment: Previous comment is about methods related to machine learninglthough for this case approaches like sound synthesis (based on selected frequencies for each instrument) might be more appropriate